# SharePoint Online Recover Deleted Security Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, disaster-recovery

Is there anyway to recover/restore deleted SharePoint Online Groups? By mistake user has deleted SharePoint groups, I couldn't find in recycle bin also. We can check with Microsoft Team. But, is there any option (OOB or custom) that we can check before asking Microsoft team. There are lot of documents in the document library having unique permissions with those SP groups. Please suggest if there is a way to restore deleted SP groups. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you delete a security group in the M365 admin center or simply remove the permission of a SharePoint group?

For M365 admin center, I am not sure if there is a way to restore it. You can open a service request for more help.

If you just remove the permission of the group in Site permissions page, you can just re-assign proper permissions there. It still will pop up in people picker. And you can find it in the SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. I could see all groups from SP designer. However there are lot of documents in document library having unique permissions with those SP groups. So I am looking for a way to restore, so all groups will restore back like before in document library. Any idea? I have updated question with more detail. Thank you....

Comment: @SriniK, per my knowledge, you will need to add them back one by one. I am not sure if we  have features to "restore" the permissions, but just re-assign. You can contact with service request to see if there are other options. And if the permission is highly similar, maybe using powershell is an option.

Comment: We have raised request with MS to do site restore.  Thanks for all your suggetions.

Comment: @SriniK, thanks for you update. Glad to hear you got a way to do this.